# An SQL query counting people younger or the same age

Tags: sql, db2

I have a problem with an SQL query. I have to count how many other employees are younger than or the same age as the employee in the current row. I tried a few ways but none of them works. It gives an error in DB2 that "The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.". This is my query:

```
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.BIRTHDATE, YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) AS AGE, COUNT(EMPNO) AS COUNT
FROM EMPLOYEE e
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) >=
(SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - BIRTHDATE) FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPNO > e.EMPNO)
GROUP BY EMPNO, e.BIRTHDATE
```

Comment: I managed to do it another way but I want to know what the problem with this query is.

Comment: You do not need backticks when your code is indented by four spaces.

Comment: Please define "Younger than or the same age as".  Your current use of `YEAR()` will select other employees born _before_ a given employee (they are older); I'm born in July, and for 10 months of a year employees born in May will be considered the "same age" as me.  Among other things, this makes **when you run the query significant** (what `CURRENT_DATE` is) - depending on the purpose here, you may need to supply a value in place of `CURRENT_DATE` to be able to retroactively figure out counts.  Depending on how this job is run, you may need to report `CURRENT_DATE` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this query is that the `SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - BIRTHDATE) FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPNO > e.EMPNO` subquery returns more than one row.

You can fix this by using a join, like this:

```
SELECT
    e.EMPNO
,   e.BIRTHDATE
,   YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) AS AGE
,   COUNT(other.EMPNO) AS COUNT
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN EMPLOYEE other
  ON other.EMPNO <> e.EMPNO AND YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - other.BIRTHDATE)
GROUP BY EMPNO, e.BIRTHDATE
```

You could also do it with a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT
    e.EMPNO
,   e.BIRTHDATE
,   YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) AS AGE
,   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE other WHERE other.EMPNO <> e.EMPNO AND YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - other.BIRTHDATE) AS COUNT
FROM EMPLOYEE e
```

Comment: @YordankaToteva You are welcome! Did either of the two queries work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `where .... >= ( subselect )`, the subselect mustn't return more than 1 row. I guess

```
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.BIRTHDATE, YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) AS AGE, COUNT(EMPNO) AS COUNT
FROM EMPLOYEE e
WHERE YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) >=
(SELECT MAX(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - BIRTHDATE)) FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPNO > e.EMPNO)
GROUP BY EMPNO, e.BIRTHDATE
```

would work - notice the MAX i inserted.

2nd attempt:

```
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.BIRTHDATE, YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE) AS AGE, COUNT(f.EMPNO)
from EMPLOYEE e, EMPLOYEE f
WHERE f.BIRTHDATE <= E.BIRTHDATE
and f.EMPNO <> e.EMPNO
GROUP BY e.EMPNO, e.BIRTHDATE, YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - e.BIRTHDATE)
```

You're joining the table with itself that way.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work as I want -  to count how many other employees are younger than or the same age as the employee in the current row. Can you give me an idea how to do it?